# Batch file for loop with Varied indexing not functioning

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, indexing, cmd

I have a for loop functioning with the /f parameter and am looking to make a script that can take a varied length section of a file and transcribe it to another file.

I have tested the code prior to the loop and it works to set the two variables to the correct numbers(22,27) but when they are entered into the loop nothing happens and it seems to skip the loop.  Similar loops function for me I believe it may just be syntax.  I've tried switching to straight numbers with no avail for tokens=a-b

```
::for testing
set end_line=27
set line=22

:WRITE_TO_FILE
::append label into COORDS
@ECHO MARKING COORDS >> COORDS.txt
for /f "tokens=%line%-%end_line% delims=@" %%a in ('findstr /b @ "board.txt"') do (
    @ECHO %%a >> COORDS.txt
    :: I want to write these lines to a separate file
    )
::END OF write to file
```

---

```
::board
"#MARKING
%
@ X125166Y137379 0 1 2
@ X196439Y137196 0 1 1
!
REGION:1,1
%"
```

Actual results are the program seeming to skip the loop and only store the label(MARKING COORDS), expected results are for the lines of a text file beginning with @ symbols within the range of line and end line to be stored / appended into a file called COORDS.txt (which already exists further up the script)

Comment: What's the content of `board.txt`?

Comment: Please also remember that batch files will impose a maximum line length limit of `8191` characters and `For /F` will limit parsing to a maximum of 32 `Tokens` too!

Comment: It is possible I have hit the line limit but I doubt it, is there a way to override the mem limit?  The contents of board.txt is a whole lot of gibberish with numbers, letters, and symbols but the lines I'm looking to extract from all have @ symbols and are between those two line numbers calculated earlier in the script.  board.txt is very long but that is why I am trying to limit the search between two values

Comment: Could you copy/paste 3-5 lines of `board.txt` into the question? Is this a plain-text file? Does it have newlines?

Comment: This is the section I am specifically trying to pull from:  #MARKING
%
@ X125166Y137379 0 1 2
@ X196439Y137196 0 1 1
!
#REGION:1,1
%

Comment: As findstr will only output lines beginning with @ your coords don't work the way intended, while it's unclear to me how they should work. Tokens are counted per line in respect to the chosen delimiters.

Comment: LotPings, as I understand it findstr will return the whole line including the @ X..., I have operations written for after that filter whitespace and extra characters.  For clarification the coordinates are simply being pulled into a text file, which will transmit to a microcontroller for further parsing and math.  I really just need to isolate those lines